# How to use Spring Data JPA with Spring&Hibernate frameworks WITHOUT springboot & maven

Tags: mysql, spring, eclipse, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Some background of what I'm doing:
I'm new to spring and hibernate and have grasped all the basics down. I'm trying to develop a webapp that has database access to MySQL.

The frameworks that I'm using are:
- Spring (Spring MVC, dependencies injection)
- Hibernate (to talk to the database)
- Hibernate validator (to validate form input fields)

My webapp is hosted locally on:
- Tomcat 9

The database I'm using is:
- MySQL 8.0

My webapp consist of:
- a controller class 
- service layer class and 
- DAO layer class

The implementation of my DAO is:
- using Hibernate Query Language (HQL)

What I am trying to do now is to replace the HQL methods of retrieving data from the database to use Spring Data JPA repository.

I've looked up tons of tutorial and guides, but they either use Springboot or Maven..

The reason I am not using Maven or Springboot is that I wish to learn from "scratch" and see how things work out so troubleshooting is easier

I've downloaded:
spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar
&
spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar

and added them to my WEB-INF library,

implementing JpaRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.assignment.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

}
```

but none of these work as I kept getting a different type of error whenever I try to resolve issues, new errors pop up

here are some of my current code

spring-mvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.assignment" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.assignment.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

    <!-- Add support for reading .properties file  -->
    <util:properties id="gradeOptions" location="classpath:../grades.properties" /> 

    <!-- Add support for reading web resources: css, images, js, etc ... -->
    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>

    <!-- Load custom message properties file -->
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">

        <property name="basenames" value="resources/errorMessages" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.assignment.entity.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {

    public List<Employee> findAll();
}
```

EmployeeRepositoryServiceImpl.java

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.assignment.dao.EmployeeRepository;
import com.assignment.entity.Employee;

@Service("employeeService")
public class EmployeeRepositoryServiceImpl implements EmployeeRepositoryService {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository theEmployeeRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findAll() {
        List<Employee> theEmployees = theEmployeeRepository.findAll();
        return theEmployees;
    }

}
```

Can anyone teach me the proper way to add Spring Data JPA into my existing dynamic web app project WITHOUT the use of Spring Boot & Maven please?

EDIT: or if anyone has any good tutorial that teaches you how to integrate Spring Data JPA onto a current Dynamic webapp project WITHOUT the use of Springboot or Maven, please kindly share, I will greatly appreciate it! :)

Comment: I strongly suggest to learn the other way around: start with the easiest setup (Maven + Boot) once that works you can do stuff more manually be removing one or the other. If you want to learn how cars works you don't start by assembling an engine from scratch but by inspecting a working car and making simple changes first.

Also: working without Maven or similar tool won't teach you much except how valuable these tools are. There job is actually fairly easy on the conceptual level.

Comment: I would strongly recommend Maven as that will save you lots of time looking for suiteable dependencies. That being said what you want will not work. Spring Data JPA is for JPA, you are using plain hibernate with a `SessionFactory` and `Session`. Spring Data JPA requires an `EntityManagerFactory`. So unless you rewrite your application with JPA it simply won't work.